# C function gives wrong result when function call on main is refactored

Tags: c

I'm writing a factorial function for practice. On main I declare the variables and call it like this:

```
int main(){
    unsigned long n = 0;
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    unsigned long result = factorial(n);
    printf("%lu \n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Which works and gives the result I want. But I thought it looked kinda bad so I refactored it like this:

```
int main(){
    unsigned long n = 0;
    printf("%lu \n", factorial(scanf("%lu", &n)));
}
```

Which somehow always gives 1 as a result no matter what. Why? Here's the factorial function just in case:

```
unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n){
    if(n == 1){
        return n;
    }
    else if(n <= 0){
        printf("No factorial for negative numbers");
    }
    else{
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I did this same exercise on Python and formatted the function call in the same way and it worked, so I'm confused as to why C doesn't accept it. Does it not call functions withing functions from the innermost first (scanf, then factorial, then printf in my case)?

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items converted or EOF, not the value of any particular item. So you're always passing 1 to `factorial` which returns 1. There's rarely any benefit in trying to fit everything on one line. Focus on writing code that is readable and easy to maintain and debug instead and your code will likely have fewer bugs.

Comment: C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization so you should prefer an iterative (loop) to recursive implementation of `factorial()`.

Comment: In `factorial()` the `return 0` is odd it only executes when `n <= 0`.  As `n` is unsigned it would make more sense to just check for `== 0` not `<= 0`. Not wrong but as each of your special cases return you don't need `else`.

Comment: Caution: Factorial multiplication will, rather quickly, generate exceedingly high values. Perhaps the code should first ensure the user's initial value will not result in overflow, returning a garbage value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Missing include.
2. As @RetiredNinja said the issue is that `scanf()` returns the number of arguments matched on success not the value of `n` and on error it returns EOF.  I added error checking here to clarify this further.
3. `factorial()`: `n` is unsigned so `n <= 0` is better written as `n == 0` or just `!n`.
4. `factorial()`: The placement of the `return 0;` statement is odd as it only executes for the case `n <= 0`.
5. `factorial()`: `return n` is not wrong but as it's a base case it's clearer to use `return 1`.
6. (Not fixed) `factorial()` on my system (with `sizeof(long) == 8`) returns 0 for `n > 65` due to overflow.  Maybe add an upper limit check?
7. (Not fixed) `factorial()`: Prefer an iterative implementation as C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization.  With sufficiently large input, on my system somewhere between n = 250k and 275k, the program will smash the stack and (hopefully) segfault.  The (default) stack size is OS specific.
8. Prefer the signature `main(void)` to `main()`.  In practice they will do the same but only the former is defined in the standard (along with `main(int, char *[])`).
9. `0!` is `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned long n;
    if(scanf("%lu", &n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%lu\n", factorial(n));
}
```

and example run:

```
6
720
```

Comment: Re: #6 "stack overflow"... 13! has already overflowed the available 32 bits of an `unsigned long`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You are right, of course, but incorrect value might be less bad then segfault (like for input -1).  Revised as suggested.  Let me know if I didn't cover your concern.

Comment: Given the limited utility of only being able to produce results for 1! to 12!, perhaps the solution is to simply hardcode those 12 values in a LUT... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 ... even on 64 bit system but it's then 65 values before overflow.  LUT might be slower at least for small values (strangely enough).

Comment: Departing from the OP's objective, it would be easy enough to change this recursive code to print the "table" of all the seeds and their factorials (from 1 to 'n')... `:-)` Something to fill a few minutes of hacking `:-)`...

Comment: `int main()` is a proper definition for `main`. In a definition, it is equivalent to `int main(void)` because they both specify there are no parameters, and C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 says equivalent declarations may be used. If it were not, the standard would have made **all** prior hosted programs using `int main()` have undefined behavior, and that was definitely not the intent.

Comment: `scanf` returns `EOF` or the number of items assigned, not the number of arguments parsed. (And arguments are not “parsed.”)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Revised as suggested.  Why don't you like "parsed"?  You evaluate the input with a format string (gramma).

Comment: @EricPostpischil  In C `main()`  means "function with no parameter specification"  (6.7.8 footnote 176) while `main(void)` means no arguments (6.9.1 p5), right?  C89, I think, and at least C17 mentions declarations (I know we talked about definitions) with empty parentheses as an obsolescent feature under future language directions.  Not sure if that actually got incorporated into 2023.   Clearly we are in agreement that it makes no difference in practice.

Comment: Hi! Back again!... A comment by @weathervane below another answer correctly points out: `0! == 1`... (Small correction needed to your award winning answer.) Here's a mathematician explaining: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @AllanWind: A function **declaration** of `foo()` that is not a definition says nothing about what the parameters are. It is governed by the grammar and semantics in C 2018 6.7. A function **definition** actually has a different grammar, specified in 6.9.1. In a definition, `()` necessarily means the function does not have any parameters. You cannot define a function with `()` and list any parameters for it. As I noted, not accepting `int main()` as equivalent to `int main(void)` for the purposes of 5.1.2.2.1 1 would make many programs undefined. Do you think the committee intended that?

Comment: Note that for any other function, a function defined as `T foo()` with no parameters in one place and declared in `T foo(void)` may be called using the latter declaration. And a function defined as `T foo(void)` and declared `T foo()` may be called using the latter declaration. This is because the rules about which function (pointer) types can call which functions are written to allow this interoperability. The types have some nominal difference, but this is due to grafting the new standard’s rules onto old practices…

Comment: … At the object level, a function defined either way must present equivalently, and a call using either must present equivalently, so they can interoperate as the standard requires. Would this be different for `main` just because some people want to interpret 5.1.2.2.1 strictly, regardless of the fact that disallowing this equivalence would both require unnecessary changes at the object level and would invalidate otherwise well defined earlier programs that used `int main()`? Why would the C committee do that; what benefit would it provide? `int main()` is just the old way, not a wrong way.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Revised as suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's always a good day when I learn something.

Answer (score 1):

`factorial(scanf("%lu", &n))` says to pass the return value of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) into `factorial`. The return value is the number of items scanned, which in this case is always going to be 0 or 1.

It's as if you wrote...

```
int num_found = scanf("%lu", &n);
unsigned long result = factorial(num_found);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the below can help:
The refactored code you provided is not producing the expected result because of the misuse of scanf and the function call within the printf statement.
Try this one :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n){
    if (n == 1){
        return n;
    }
    else if (n <= 0){
        printf("No factorial for negative numbers");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long n = 0;
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    unsigned long result = factorial(n);
    printf("%lu \n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The factorial of zero is 1, not 0 as your code. Also, there is nothing wrong with having a function call as a parameter of `printf`, so `printf("%lu \n", factorial(n));`